# LGBMRanking Model "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples"

Tags: python, lightgbm

X and Y = 44980

group = 3

Data is time series, X contain features + the item being ranked

| Date | Item | Feature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/27 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/27 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/27 | 3 | 1 |
| 9/28 | 1 | 0 |
| 9/28 | 2 | 0 |
| 9/28 | 3 | 0 |

y contains the rank of the item

| Date | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| 9/27 | 3 |
| 9/27 | 2 |
| 9/27 | 1 |
| 9/28 | 2 |
| 9/28 | 3 |
| 9/28 | 1 |

But when running LGBM Ranker on the following data, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 62, in <module>
    score = cross_val_score(model, X=X, y=y,
  File "\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 515, in cross_val_score
    cv_results = cross_validate(
  File "\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 252, in cross_validate
    X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
  File "\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 429, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 383, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [44980, 44980, 3]
```

Code:

```
paths_dict = {'1':'../../1.csv',
              '2':'../../2.csv',
              '3':'../../3.csv',}
def load_paths(paths_dict):
  df = pd.DataFrame()
  for key, value in paths_dict.items():
    df[key] = pd.read_csv(value, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)['Close']
  df = df.iloc[::-1]
  return df
df = load_paths(paths_dict)
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Date', 'Item', 'Target']
df['Item'] = df['Item'].astype('int')
df['Target'] = df.groupby('Date')['Target'].rank('dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

y = df['Target']
X = df.drop(['Target'], axis=1)
model = LGBMRanker(n_jobs=-1)
score = cross_val_score(model, X=X, y=y,
                        groups=X.groupby('Item'),
                        cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=24),
                        scoring=make_scorer(ndcg_score))
```

Comment: Show us the entire error message traceback.

Comment: Now show us `code.py`.

Comment: @JohnGordon added that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sklearn doesnt support ranking models